# What is the subdifferential of the $f(x)$?

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

$$f(x_1,x_2)=2|x_1|+3|x_2|$$

I did a plot of this function:

[image: subdifferential]

The subgradient should be on the red peak on the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\partial f(x_1,x_2) = 2\mathrm{Sgn}(x_1)\times3 \mathrm{Sgn}(x_2),$$
where 
$$\mathrm{Sgn}(y) := \begin{cases}
\{-1\}, &\text{if $y<0$;}\\
[-1,1], &\text{if $y=0$;}\\
\{1\}, &\text{if $y>0$}
\end{cases}
$$
because $f$ is separable, the subdifferential of the absolute-value function is $\mathrm{Sgn}$, and the constant-multiple rule applies.

Now, the "peak on the bottom" is at $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. At this point, we have $$\partial f(0,0)=[-2,2]\times[-3,3].$$

Comment: What do you mean by "constant-multiple rule apply"?

Comment: If $\alpha > 0$, then $\partial (\alpha g) = \alpha \partial g$. This is applied twice with $\alpha=3$ and $\alpha=2$, where $g$ is the absolute-value function.

Comment: are there other points than f(0,0)?

Comment: $f(0,0)$ is a function value, the real number $0$ at this point. I am not sure I follow your question. The subdifferential is a set of vectors associated with a vector. The formula above gives you the subdifferential at any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.